# Leaking internal storage

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, insufficient-memory, moto-x

I have a Motorola Moto X Play with 16GB of internal storage and and additional micro SD card (64 GB), formatted as extended internal storage. I am trying to free up the internal storage, so I went through a manual excercise to move Apps to the SD card. However, the internal storage I should have freed is leaked in some way.

In Storage & USB / Internal Storage I have 10.32GB used out of 11.00GB, Apps take 5.54GB, other stuff <50MB. Where is my missing 5GB? How can I recover it?

What I am missing is the ~5GB of internal storage that is not used by Apps and not attributed to anything on Storage & USB / Internal Storage – I'm not speaking of the difference between 16GB (device nominal size) and 11 GB (total internal storage), which certainly is used by other partitions like `/system`.

The phone is not rooted.

Comment: @Izzy, The 5GB reserved for system you are thinking about is the difference between 16GB (device nominal size) and 11 GB (total internal storage). What I am missing is the ~5GB of internal storage that is not used by Apps and not attributed to anything on Storage & USB / Internal Storage.

Comment: Ah, OK – your description is a bit ambiguous then. Let's integrate that into the question itself (before it confuses others as well) and cleanup comments then. // My Edit OK with you? And maybe you could integrate some screenshot(s) of the storage screen for "visuals"?

Comment: What comes to mind then are Caches and Logs (for the latter, especially "[Tombstones](/search?q=tombstones)", which can take up quite some space). Caches can easily be cleared (eg. via recovery), so you could give that a try. Tombstones are more difficult, especially on a non-rooted device (check the link to our search; AFAIR there was some service menu for that; to simply see if it's worse a "closer look" in your case, check the end of [my answer here](/a/27130/16575)).

Comment: Definitely /data takes is the partition that I am about, but `cd /data/tombstones' gives me access denied :(. Is rooting a phone complicated/dangerous? Maybe I should just get it done and clean it properly...

Comment: Very much depends on the device. Take a look at our [rooting tag-wiki](/tags/rooting/info) for an overview.